# Inequality involving binomial cofficients

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

let $n,k,m,\ell$ be positive integers satisfying $k\le n-m,k\le n-\ell$. I am trying to prove the following inequality:
$$X=\frac{\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-m}{k}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-1-\ell}{k-1}} \le \frac{n}{k}\cdot \frac{m}{\ell}$$
It might be that the cofficient $n/k$ is sligntly different, for instance $(n-1)/(k-1)$ or something like that. 
I have tried to upper bound it using common techniques, for example:
$$X=\frac{\binom{n}{k}(\binom{n-m}{k}/\binom{n}{k})}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}(\binom{n-1-\ell}{k-1}/\binom{n-1}{k-1}}$$
$$X=\frac{\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-m)\dots(n-m-(k-1)}{n(n-1)\dots(n-(k-1))}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-1-(k-1)}{(n-1-\ell)\dots(n-1-\ell-(k-1)}}$$
And now we can use the fact that whenm $0\le i\le k$ we have 
$$\frac{n}{m}\le \frac{n-i}{n-m-i}\le \frac{n-k}{n-m-k} $$
To conclude: 
$$ X\le \frac{\binom{n}{k}(1-(1-\frac{m}{n})^k)}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}(1-(1-\frac{\ell}{n-k})^k)}$$
$$=\frac{n}{k}\cdot\frac{1-(1-\frac{m}{n})^k}{1-(1-\frac{\ell}{n-k})^k}$$
However, when I try to upper bound this by using inequalities for $(1-x)^t$ for the nominator and denominator, it seems that the denominator cannot be controled properly. I'm guessing that the inequality used for $(*)$ is a bit too loose and might be possible to improve.

Comment: I have a doubt in the factor $\tfrac m\ell$. For instance, when $k$ is constant, $n$ is big, $m\approx an$, $\ell\approx bn$ for  some constants $a$ and $b$, we have $$X\approx\frac{\tfrac {n^k}{k!}- \tfrac {(1-a)^k n^k}{k!}} {\tfrac {n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}- \tfrac {(1-b)^{k-1} n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}}=\frac nk\cdot \frac {1-(1-a)^k}{1-(1-b)^{k-1}}.$$ In particular, when $k=2$ and $0<a<1$ then $$X\approx 
\frac nk\cdot \frac {2a-a^2}{b}\gg \frac nk\cdot \frac {a}{b}\approx \frac nk\cdot \frac {m}{\ell}.$$